# How can I group three tables into one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Table 1-ApplicationUser 
UserID UserName

1--------user1
2--------user2

Table 2-UserShip

UserShipID UserID ShıpID
1-----------1------1 
2-----------2------1

Table 3 -UserCar

UserCarID UserID CarID
1---------1--------1
2---------2---------2

I have 3 tables and I want to display these three tables as follows.

UserName - Car COUNT - SHIPCOUNT
user1-----  1 ------------1

I want to list the username, the number of cars and ships he owns. What sql code should I write? I couldn't group it somehow, can you help me?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL-Server

Comment: Please tag with the database platform you are actually using

Comment: Hint...you need LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  ApplicationUser.UserID,
  ApplicationUser.UserName,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CarID) AS OwnedCars,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ShipID) AS OwnedShips
FROM
  ApplicationUser
  LEFT JOIN UserCar ON UserCar.UserID = ApplicationUser.UserID
  LEFT JOIN UserShip ON UserShip.UserID = ApplicationUser.UserID
GROUP BY
  ApplicationUser.UserID, ApplicationUser.UserName
```

Comment: This should work on both SQL Server and MySQL, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks, @SeanLange - Rookie mistake.

Comment: Bro you are awesome, thank you. I love you, you saved me big problem <3